# batch script to open an command window and run directory scan

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script which opens a

1) command window

2) get the command prompt pointing to c (come to root)

3)run dir /s command which performs an extensive scan of the system starting from the root.

The window should not dissapear.

but i' m only able to come to come to c prompt and the command window disappears, i have posted the script here . Please let me know where exactly i'm going wrong .

```
start cmd /c cd / && dir /s
```

**EDIT** : The issue is fixed

**ANSWER**

```
 start cmd /c 
cd / && dir /s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cmd` with the `/k` switch to pass in your commands, such as:

```
cmd /k "pushd C: & cd\ & dir /s"
```